# How to use aliased column day in WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about this query:

```
  SELECT DAYOFYEAR(t.ts_start) AS 'day', YEAR(t.ts_start) AS year, t.o AS value FROM Cryptoforecast_ETH_BTC_1h AS t
```

when I run it it shows the results. Now i want to filter for day adding a `WHERE` statement like this

```
SELECT DAYOFYEAR(t.ts_start) AS 'day', YEAR(t.ts_start) AS year, t.o AS value FROM Cryptoforecast_ETH_BTC_1h AS t WHERE 'day'=157
```

But it gies no result and a warning:

```
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'day'
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Try this ,   `SELECT DAYOFYEAR(t.ts_start) AS day, YEAR(t.ts_start) AS year, t.o AS value FROM Cryptoforecast_ETH_BTC_1h AS t HAVING  day =157
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just repeat the call to `DAYOFYEAR` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
    DAYOFYEAR(t.ts_start) AS day,
    YEAR(t.ts_start) AS year,
    o AS value
FROM Cryptoforecast_ETH_BTC_1h
WHERE DAYOFYEAR(t.ts_start) = 157;
```

Or, if you want to use the `day` alias, you may do so with an overloaded `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
    DAYOFYEAR(t.ts_start) AS day,
    YEAR(t.ts_start) AS year,
    o AS value
FROM Cryptoforecast_ETH_BTC_1h
HAVING day = 157;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use alias column in your `WHERE` clause. So, you aren't actually compare column instead string value with int.

```
WHERE 'day'=157
```

instead you could use

```
WHERE DAYOFYEAR(t.ts_start) = 157
```

**Side note :** You don't need to use single quote for your column alias.